# Formula to list data in two or more column ranges, excluding blank rows

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

| a | b | c | d | e | f |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
|  |  |  |  |  | result |
| 1 | q | 4 | r |  | q |
| 2 | w | 5 | t |  | w |
| 3 | e | 6 |  |  | e |
|  | r | 7 |  |  | r |
|  |  | 8 |  |  | r |
|  |  |  |  |  | t |
|  |  |  |  |  |  |
|  |  |  |  |  |  |
|  |  |  |  |  |  |

[image]

Column ranges must be used from row 3 to the entire row.

The range referring to the image is B3:B column, D3:D column. Please ignore columns A and C.

The result must not contain blank cells.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
=QUERY(FLATTEN(TRANSPOSE(FILTER(A3:D,MOD(COLUMN(A3:D),2)=0))),"where Col1 is not null")
```